# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError eof while reading when collecting data through Google APIs in a Rails 7 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, openssl

I use the google-apis-gmail_v1 gem in a Rails 7 app. It is deployed on Scalingo, an heroku-like PaaS solution.

I collect email headers at a large scale through the Gmail API with sidekiq/redis jobs. But I am facing a lot of errors in my log system, making each mailbox sync almost eternal : it has to restart every time this exception is raised.

Error thrown :

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=142.250.178.138:443 state=error: unexpected eof while reading
```

Still, the data collection works well both in production console and through the sidekiq/redis flow, which means some full sync do work until the end without raising this error.

I don't know at what level i should change parameters to try some things : docker image of the PaaS provider ; rails configuration ; google certificates. The IP in the error is a Google IP address.